What is the mathematical form of recoil heating rates in detuned optical lattices with a trapped 2-state atom?
I am having problems understanding the recoil heating mechanism in optical lattices. Asking ChatGPT, it follows some form $\Gamma_{heat} = E_{rec} \Gamma_{sp}$ where $E_{rec}$ is the recoil energy and $\Gamma_{sp}$ is the spontaneous emission rate. In explicit form, I got $E_{rec} = \frac{(\hbar \vec{k})^2}{2m}$ where $\vec{k}$ is the wave vector of the radiation field and $\Gamma_{sp}=\frac{\Gamma \Omega^2}{2 \Delta^2}$.
My problem in understanding is the origin of those formulae.

For the recoil heating, I would guess that the mechanism looks somewhat like this $| g,\vec p \rangle \rightarrow | e,\vec p + \hbar \vec k \rangle \rightarrow | g,\vec p + \hbar (\vec k + \vec k') \rangle$. Is this correct?

For the spontaneous emission, I don't know where to begin. I would guess that the emission rate follows some $\Gamma_{sp} \propto \rho_{ee}$, which (in equilibrium) likely depends on $\Omega$ and $\Delta$...

As a follow-up question: If this is indeed the correct form, do blue-detuned optical lattices suffer less heating than red-detuned ones? My intuition tells me that since blue-detuned intensity maxima repel the atoms in the lattice, they accumulate at intensity minima, whereas in the red-detuned case this happens at the maxima, giving $\Omega_{blue} << \Omega_{red}$, and subsequently $\Gamma_{heat,blue} << \Gamma_{heat,red}$.


Thank you in advance for any insight!
